# Counterexample for $\int\sum_1^\infty f_j = \sum_1^\infty \int f_j$?

Tags: real-analysis

Theorem 2.25 of Folland's book says that:

Suppose $\{f_j\}$ is a sequence in $L^1$ such that $\sum_1^\infty\int\mid f_j \mid< \infty$. Then $\sum_1^\infty f_j$ converges a.e. to an $L^1$ function, and $\int\sum_1^\infty f_j = \sum_1^\infty \int f_j$.

In the proof, the assumption that $\sum_1^\infty\int\mid f_j \mid< \infty$ implies that $\sum_1^\infty f_j$ converges a.e.  and is in $L^1$ and then uses the dominant convergence theorem to prove the result.

My question is that, if instead of assuming $\sum_1^\infty\int\mid f_j \mid< \infty$, we assume that $\sum_1^\infty f_j$ converges a.e. to an $L^1$ function, can we prove $\int\sum_1^\infty f_j = \sum_1^\infty \int f_j$ or one can find a counterexample for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $f_1=1_{[0,1]}$,$f_k=-1_{[k-2,k-1]}+1_{[k-1,k]}$ for $k \geq 2$. Then the sum converges a.e. to zero but the sum of the integrals is $1$. To make up similar examples, just consider violating hypotheses of the Vitali Convergence Theorem. (In this case I violated tightness, but you can also violate uniform integrability.)

Answer (score 1):

This is an example from an exercise problem of *Probability and Measure* by *Patrick Billingsley*.
Consider $f_n(x) = x^{n - 1} - 2x^{2n - 1}, x \in (0, 1)$. 
It can be checked that 
\begin{align}
\sum_n f_n(x) = \frac{1}{1 + x} \in L_1((0, 1)),
\end{align}
while 
$$\sum_n \int_0^1 f_n(x) dx = 0 \neq \int_0^1 \sum_n f_n(x) dx = \log 2.$$